# when can two primes, both equivalent to 1 modulo 4, be a square modulo one another.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have two primes p and q, p $\equiv$ 1 (mod 4) and q $\equiv$ 1 (mod4). It is well known that either both p and q are square modulo each-other or not.

I am trying to look for a condition for them to actually be squares modulo one another. However, I am having trouble. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion): $q$ is a square mod $p$ iff $q^{(p-1)/2} \equiv 1 \mod p$.  This works for any $q$ coprime to an odd prime $p$.